# VPS DNS Records Multiple Domains

Tags: web-hosting, vps, multiple-domains

I am very new to using a VPS (two days old) and have a limited understanding of hosting in general, so sorry if this is a very simple or ill-explained question.

I just purchased a VPS with plesk installed and am in the process of pointing my domains to the new server.

The server has the following nameservers:

ns1.mydomain.com (123.123.123.123) <- fake

ns2.mydomain.com (123.123.123.124) <- fake

What I don't understand is now that I have pointed my domain to ns1.mydomain.com and ns2.mydomain.com how would I point another domain of mine to that server?

I have setup a domain in my plesk control panel, does this happen automatically?

For example, if I setup "anotherdomain.com" in the cp, can I just point "anotherdomain.com" to ns1.mydomain.com and it will work?

Help!

Comment: I'm afraid, but "...pointing my domains to the new server..." is too broad and vague action that does not have a clear **technical** equivalent

"When in Rome, do as the Romans do", so - if you do hostmaster's job, you *have to use* commonly accepted and used terms.

I, at least, can imagine **two different and slightly related tasks** from "pointing domains" definition:

1. You want to register new domains and use NS on your VPS as authoritative NS-servers
2. You have registered live domains (NSes are on independent 3-rd party side servers) and want to place some sites on your VPS only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have several domain names using the same name server as long as you are using virtual hosts in the web server. That's the whole point of virtual hosts: to be able to run many domain names on a single web server!

Be sure that the domain names are correctly configured in the name sever, and that you have set up the HTTP server to handle virtual hosting, and that you have all the different domain names set up as virtual hosts.

Comment: Actually, I think you're confusing 2 separate issues. The DNS server isn't the web server. It can host the DNS records for as many domains as you want, regardless of the webserver setup. It's also possible to point multiple domains to a single nameserver, but the nameserver directs DNS requests for each domain to a separate server--no vhosts required.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, I updated my post to use "name server" instead of DNS. I think what the person is asking is related to running multiple domains on a single VM, so I was trying to explain how to do that using virtual hosts and single nameserver.